# Запись в массив byte[] данных из файла(?самый рациональный подход)

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Существует некий файл. Ссылка: `@"./input.txt"`

Содержание файла - квадрат некой размерности M N из нулей и единиц
пример

```
0 1 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
```

Нужно записать его в массив типа byte[] размерностью M+1 N+1(записать сам массив в правый нижний угол, чтобы слева был столбец с 0 и сверху была строка с 0)
т.е.:

```
0 1 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
```

в:

```
   0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 1 0 1 1
   0 0 0 1 0 0
   0 1 1 1 0 0
   0 0 0 0 1 0
```

Решил сначала записать в отдельный массив, позже перезаписать в массив M+1 N+1
Но, думаю, это не самый рациональный подход.

**Вопрос:** Как рационально провести вышеописанные действия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любым из тысячи возможных способов.

Например:

```
File.ReadLines(filename)
    .Select(l => l.Split()
                  .Select(byte.Parse)
                  .ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Это создаёт массив массивов. Чтобы добавить нулевую строку и столбец, нужно чуть больше кода:

```
var result =
    new byte[][] { null }.Concat(
        File.ReadLines(filename)
            .Select(l => new byte[] { 0 }.Concat(
                           l.Split()
                            .Select(byte.Parse))
                         .ToArray())
        )
        .ToArray();

// вставляем нулевую строку
var length = result[1].Length;
result[0] = Enumerable.Repeat((byte)0, length).ToArray();
```

Код выходит не сильно читаемый, поэтому я бы отказался от массива и перешёл к `List<List<byte>>`:

```
var result = 
    File.ReadLines(filename)
        .Select(l => l.Split()
                      .Select(byte.Parse)
                      .ToList())
        .ToList();
foreach (var list in result)
    list.Insert(0, 0);
var length = result[0].Count;
result.Insert(0, Enumerable.Repeat((byte)0, length).ToList();
```

Не беспокойтесь о скорости: всё равно доминирующим фактором будет чтение с диска.

---

@Qwertiy подсказал, что вместо `.Select(n => byte.Parse(n))` можно использовать более лаконичную конструкцию `.Select(byte.Parse)` — спасибо!

Comment: `Select(n => byte.Parse(n))` хорошо заменяется на `Select(byte.Parse)`.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Хм, и правда. Я думал, что другие перегрузки помешают — оказывается, нет. Сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 5):

"Рационально" в вашем вопросе звучит неоднозначно. Рациональность/эффективность бывает разной, при этом, очень часто, еще и взаимоисключающей.

Например, можно рационально использовать память, нерациональным будет читабельность (сопровождаемость кода), и, возможно, производительность.

Можно рационализировать эффективность, но, опять же, читаемость кода будет низкой, а расход памяти - высоким.

Обычно, следует "рационализировать" свою собственную эффективность, добиваясь простого и читаемого кода, на основе которого легко добиться другой рациональности: по памяти или времени исполнения.

В данном же случае, наиболее оптимальным подходом, кажется вычитывание вашего файла в список `BitArray`-ов. Это будет рационально с точки зрения памяти и производительности:

```
static IEnumerable<BitArray> FromFile(string path)
{

    using (var file = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        string str;
        while ((str = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // Парсим строку, 
            var bitArray = new BitArray( ... );
            yield return bitArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Тут остается вопрос, с нулевой строкой и колонкой. Эту задачу можно возложить на другой метод, или же делать все в методе вычитывания.

Comment: Разве `BitArray` с точки зрения производительности рациональнее обычного массива?

Comment: Рациональнее, поскольку в исходной задаче нужно хранить только 0 или 1. А это значит, что BitArray в 8 раз эффективнее обычного массива.

Comment: По памяти - да. Но по производительности почему? Ведь каждое обращение к биту будет выполнять дополнительные операции, а именно несколько битовых сдвигов и and'ов. Действительно ли попадание в кэш большего объёма данных перевешивает эти операции?

Comment: Согласен. Нужно мерять. Вполне возможно, что массив будет быстрее, но менее эффективно. Хотя тут могут сыграть такие вещи как локальность данных. В общем, нужно профилировать.

Comment: Хм.. Только сейчас подумал: ведь в плюсах решили, что надо ужимать `vector <bool>` до битов - так что, наверное, проигрыш или очень незначительный, или его совсем нет. Иначе бы они переложили ответственность за выбор способа на программиста, но они так не поступили.

Comment: Вполне возможно, что это обычный компромис: память vs. время исполнения. В одних случаях важнее одно, а в других - другое.
Так что все равно нужно мерять, чтобы понять, важно это или нет.

Comment: Согласен. Просто задумался об их логике. Зачем награждать `vector <bool>` особым поведением, если можно сделать отдельный класс по примеру `bitset`? У плюсов же цель максимальная производительность и в случае существенной разницы было бы логично сделать два класса и оставить выбор между ними за программистом. Но они так не поступили (конечно, можно поставить `char` вместо `bool`, но этот путь не похож на предоставление выбора). Значит, логично предположить, что в большинстве случаев существенного проигрыша нет.

Comment: Насколько я помню, vector<bool> considered harmful и это был просто пример специализации шаблонов.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38661/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-sergey-teplyakov).

Answer (score 1):

Если файл небольшой - то рационально сделать как проще.

Если файл большой - то читайте через `File.ReadLines` с последующей построчной конвертацией. Примерно так:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Projects\1.txt");
var numberOfColumns = lines.First().Length / 2 + 2;

int [] firstLine = Enumerable.Repeat(0, numberOfColumns).ToArray();

int[][] result = new int[][] { firstLine }
    .Concat(
        lines.Select(l => ("0 " + l).Split(' ').Select(t => t == "0" ? 0 : 1).ToArray())
        )
    .ToArray();
```